# Is it possible to copy whole blob of a container (having files)to another subscription container blob in java

Tags: java, azure, azure-storage

I want to copy data from blob e.g storageaccount/container/folder1/folder2/folder3 . Now I want to copy folder3 data to another subscription container blob.

I am using java and azure sdk, startcopy to copy source to destination using SAS. but everytime it says that blob does not exist.

But if source path I give like this : storageaccount/container/folder1/folder2/folder3/xyz.txt then it is able to copy data from source to destination.
Cant we copy whole folder3 data to destination?instead of looping through all the files?

Comment: Please edit your question and include the code you have written.

Comment: Regarding the issue, you can try to use azcopy to implement it. For more details, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-blobs#copy-a-directory-to-another-storage-account

Answer (score 0):

You mention `startcopy` method, suppose you are using v8 sdk. You say when use `storageaccount/container/folder1/folder2/folder3` it will say that blob does not exist, cause you just provide a directory and the [startcopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.cloudblockblob.startcopy?view=azure-java-legacy) need the `CloudBlockBlob` object.

So the right way should be list the blobs under the directory, then loop the blobs and copy the blob. The below is my test code, for test I just copy a directory to another container.

```
        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.parse(connectStr);
        CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.createCloudBlobClient();
        try {
            CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.getContainerReference("test");
            Iterable<ListBlobItem> blobs=container.listBlobs("testfolder/");
            CloudBlobContainer destcontainer=blobClient.getContainerReference("testcontainer");

            for(ListBlobItem blob:blobs){
                CloudBlockBlob srcblob=new CloudBlockBlob(blob.getUri());
                CloudBlockBlob destblob= destcontainer.getBlockBlobReference(srcblob.getName());
                destblob.startCopy(srcblob);

            }

        } catch (StorageException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

**Update**: about the status about copy action, there is a method [getCopyState](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.microsoft.azure.storage.file.cloudfile.getcopystate?view=azure-java-legacy), you could get the state details, hope this is what you want. More details check the method.

```
CopyState st=destblob.getCopyState();
System.out.println(st.getStatus());
```

Comment: Thanks.Do we need to add SAS? Also, how can I track the status of copy ?

Comment: If you want to do that you could add sas, about  status of copy, check my updated answer.

Comment: @sar, any process on this issue? If this cold help you, you could accept it as the answer follow this [link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).